# Functions of uniform density

Tags: random-variables

Consider the random variable X with the uniform
density having $α = 1$ and $β = 3$.
(a) Use the result of Example 2 to find the probability
density of $Y = |X|$

In example two they showed that such a function(Y=|X|) would have the density of the form:
$g(y) = \begin{cases} f(y) + f(-y) \space \text{for} \space y>0 \\ 0 \space \text{elsewhere} \end{cases}$

I have learnt two techinques, distribution function technique and transformation in one variable technique. 
The answer given in the book:
$\frac{1}{8} y^{−3/4} $  for  $ 0 < y < 1$ and 
$g(y) =\frac{1}{4}$ for $1 <y < 3$

I'm totally lost in this question

Shouldn't there be distribution only for $1<y<3$? Why is $0<y<1$ there? 
Even if both are there I'm not getting anything close to the two given answers, just getting weird answers like 1 and 1/2

Comment: What do you think how the distribution of $X$ looks like? And what is the result of example 2?

Comment: Apologies, have now put in info about example 2

Comment: Looks to me the distribution of $|X|$ is the same as that of $X$. Have you quoted the question correctly?

Comment: The question is quoted correctly